# Call API untill certain response

Tags: javascript

I really struggle with async functions in Javasctipt. Here I have async function that calls api and saves the result. It is working fine but I need to make a loop now so this api is called untill certain condition is met. I understand that it needs to be done using await but I just can't figure out how exactly.

I tried setting up if statement and then doing something like "if condition is not met" setTimeout(getResults()); (repeat the call to async function).

```
async getResults() {

    try {

        const res = await axios(`https://blablabla`);
        this.result = res.data.info;

    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async getResults() {

try {
    let i = 100;
    while(i-->=0){

    const res = await axios(`https://blablabla`);
    this.result = res.data.info;
    if(this.result == 'some process finished')
    {
        return this.result;
    }
    //else retry
    }

} catch (error) {
    alert(error);
}
```

just use some cycle like while(true). And repeat body of cycle until your conditions are met